# How could I uncast a void* that I don't know the data type?

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I have a structure with two different `std::multimap`. I would like to do something like this but, how could I uncast a `void*` that I don't know the data type is?

```
struct Data{
  std::multimap<uint64_t,uint64_t, std::greater<uint64_t>> b;
  std::multimap<uint64_t,uint64_t, std::less<uint64_t>> s;
};

Data data;

void do_something(bool c){
    void* pointer;
    uint64_t cumulative = 0;
    if(c){
        pointer = &data.b;
    } else {
        pointer = &data.s;
    }
    /*      Here I don't know if pointer is
    *           std::multimap<uint64_t,uint64_t, std::greater<uint64_t>>
    *           or
    *           std::multimap<uint64_t,uint64_t, std::less<uint64_t>>
    */
    for(auto it = (*pointer).begin(); it != (*pointer).end(); ++it){ 
        cumulative += it->second;
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't go through `void*`, write a small function template to do the accumulation (or see if `std::accumulate` doesn't already fit your need).

Comment: `std::variant` or `std::any`

Comment: "How could I uncast a void* that I don't know the data type?" You don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional information, you won't know that the underlying type is. Hence, casting a `void*` to any type pointer type is error prone.

You can deal with your situation using a different strategy.

```
template <typename Iter>
uint64_t do_something(Iter start, Iter end)
{
   uint64_t cumulative = 0;
   for(auto it = start; it != end; ++it){ 
      cumulative += it->second;
   }
   return cumulative;
}

void do_something(bool c)
{
   uint64_t cumulative = 0;
   if(c)
   {
      cumulative = do_something(data.b.begin(), data.b.end());
   }
   else
   {
      cumulative = do_something(data.s.begin(), data.s.end());
   }
}
```

You can use [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to simplify the first function.

```
template <typename Iter>
uint64_t do_something(Iter start, Iter end)
{
   return std::accumulate(start, end, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How could I uncast a void* that I don't know the data type?

You could not do so.

You can only cast to a type that you know.

For something like this, you can write a function template that operates on any range:

```
template<class Range>
void do_something_template(Range& r){
    // do something
}

void do_something(bool c){
    uint64_t cumulative = c
        ? do_something_template(data.b)
        : do_something_template(data.s);
```

That said, there is already a standard algorithm for what you are doing in this particular case: `std::accumulate` and there is no need to rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks! std::accumulate may be useful to me

Answer (score 0):

You can't dereference the void-pointer, but in your case you can do like this:

```cpp
template<typename Container>
uint64_t do_something_helper(const Container& container)
{
    uint64_t cumulative = 0;
    for (const auto& item : container) {
        cumulative += item.second;
    }
    return cumulative;
}

void do_something(bool c)
{
    uint64_t cumulative = [&]() {
        if (c) {
            return do_something_helper(data.b);
        }
        else {
            return do_something_helper(data.s);
        }
    }();

    // Do something with cumulative
}
```

Moreover. Here is `std::any` in C++17:

```
void do_something(bool c)
{
    std::any container;
    if (c) {
        container = data.b;
    }
    else {
        conainter = data.s;
    }

    try {
        auto* pCont = std::any_cast<decltype(data.b)>( &container );
        for ( ... ) {
            // compute cumulative
        }
    }
    catch(const std::bad_any_cast&) {
        auto* pCont = std::any_cast<decltype(data.s)>( &container );
        for ( ... ) {
            // compute cumulative
        }
    }
}
```

But for me the first solution looks a bit better, than second one :)

Comment: The idea is not to repeat pieces of code. I think the first option works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With just `void*`, you cannot. However, here are two possible solutions (with different levels of intrusiveness):

1. You can also encode the type some way, e.g. with an enum, and use that to `static_cast` back to the concrete type.

```
struct A {};
struct B {};

enum class Type
{
    A,
    B,
};

void do_something(bool c)
{
    A a;
    B b;

    void* pointer;
    Type type;

    if (c)
    {
        pointer = &a;
        type = Type::A;
    }
    else
    {
        pointer = &b;
        type = Type::B;
    }

    if (type == Type::A)
    {
        A* concrete = static_cast<A*>(pointer);
        // Use concrete here as A.
    }
    else if (type == Type::B)
    {
        B* concrete = static_cast<B*>(pointer);
        // Use concrete here as B.
    }
}
```

2. Make your types polymorphic (with virtual functions and a common base class). Instead of `void*` make `pointer` a pointer to the common base class, and you can `dynamic_cast` to the concrete type.

I would note however that usually in a well-designed program, polymorphic usage of types should not need to ever know the concrete type. Look into using virtual functions or `std::variant`.